# MySQL Show a test result based on the value of the field

Tags: mysql, select, field

I have a table called **PEOPLE** that shows

**Name**   **Sex**
++++   ++++++
Tom      1
Jane     2

In the sex column the numbers equal gender 1=Male 2=Female

I would like to

Select Name, Sex (replacing either 1 or 2 with Male or Female) from people

The result showing

Tom    **Male**
Jane   **Female**

I do not wish to alter the data in the DB just change the way the data is presented from the select.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Name, case Sex 
               when 1 then 'Male' 
               else 'Female' 
             end
from people
```